# How do you create one rule overriding rules for individual pages?

Tags: .htaccess

I have:

```
    RewriteRule ^for-auto.html index.php?show=for-auto [L]
    RewriteRule ^for-home.html index.php?for=dla-home [L]
    RewriteRule ^cleaning-service.html index.php?show=cleaning-service [L]
```

How to create one rule for all of the pages above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this Rule :

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ index.php?show=$1 [L,NC]
```

Reference : http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule

Hope this helps you!